# Fast Report Aliases x Templates

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I defined aliases for the fields to provide friendly names in the template edition. The problem is that these friendly names are localized and FastReport saves the template with the Aliases, not the Field Names! That doesn't seem very clever.

If I take a template that was created in language A and try to use it with language B, it raises a lot of errors because the fields are not found anymore. Or worse, if someone decides that one particular translation isn't good and change it, that field won't be found anymore.

Is there a way to have friendly names for the fields without substituting the field names of the template that will be saved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since FastReports saves all its report templates as XML files, it could be that the easiest way to accomplish what you want to do is write a routine that will read the FastReport XML file and iterate through all of the TfrxMemoView nodes changing the Text attribute to the friendly local name.

Comment: And also change from Friendly Name back to Field Name to save the template. I'd have to do a lot of substitutions back and forth... it works... but it's too jury-rig for me. I hope there is a better way.